# You can't use `\eqno' in math mode,Missing } inserted

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, braces

I understand from previous post that this error come when you have extra {,( involved. But in my case i am not able to find any such case.

```
\begin{equation}\overset{\wedge}{\pi}\left(\beta/ A_n\right) =
    \sum_{\alpha\epsilonA_n}\frac{n_\alpha}{n}\int
    exp(-t){F_{\alpha_1\beta_1}^\left(\theta,t,n\right)}.....{F_{\alpha_L\beta_L}^\left(\theta,t,n\right)}dt
 \end{equation}
```

Can anybody point me out the error?  is wrong with this? . I am getting 6 errors in this i.e.

```
Undefined control sequence. \sum_{\alpha\epsilonA
Missing { inserted. exp(-t){F_{\alpha_1\beta_1}^\left
Missing { inserted. ...ight)}.........{F_{\alpha_L\beta_L}^\left
You can't use `\eqno' in math mode. \end{equation}
Missing } inserted. \end{equation}
Missing } inserted. \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typing errors like `\sum_{\alpha\epsilonA_n}` and misplaced curly braces ... try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\overset{\wedge}{\pi}
\left(\beta/ A_n\right) =
    \sum_{\alpha\epsilon A_n}\frac{n_\alpha}{n}
    \int\exp(-t) F_{\alpha_1\beta_1}^{\left(\theta,t,n\right)} \dots F_{\alpha_L\beta_L}^{\left(\theta,t,n\right)}dt
 \end{equation}
Compare:
 \[\hat{\pi}\quad\widehat{\pi}\quad\overset{\wedge}{\pi}\]

    \end{document}
```

Also see, if the `\hat{\pi}` or `\widehat{\pi}` is more situated than `\overset{\wedge}{\pi}`.

[image]